# My python code for SQLite has not made the insert data permenant as when I try to do a select query no data is outputted

Tags: python, sqlite

When I try to do a select query it shows up with nothing and I do not know why that is when I call it in a different function

This is the creating table code

[image: This is the creating table code]

This is the code which will insert data

[image: This is the code which will insert data]

I tried an SQL select statement and i was expecting for it to give me the code of a teacher however this issue is that it displays nothing.

This is the output

[image]

Comment: Don't post your code as images.

Answer (score 3):

As per [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), the insert statement implicitly opens a transaction. You need to call `connection_obj.commit()` to commit the transaction once you are done inserting rows.